# Show message if update time is less tha 8 hours in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, time, laravel-blade

Maybe is something simple but I have one submit form which I want to restrict so user should be able to update it once per 8 hours.

I have `updated_at` column in database table which store last update time in `timestamp` : `2016-10-21 09:56:13`

Now in my blade template I've tried to check like this

```
@if($time->updated_at < 8 hour)                 
    // show message to come back after 8 hours                                                          
@else
    // show the form
@endif
```

I've got

> 'syntax error, unexpected 'hour' (T_STRING)'

I know why I got this but I don't how to make the if... do I need to convert current time and then how to present 8 hours? Like `60*60*8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `updated_at` is using Laravel's default timestamps

```
@if((time() - strtotime($time->updated_at)) < 28800)                 
    // show message to come back after 8 hours                                                          
@else
    // show the form
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using larvel timestamps than updated_at is always the object of carbon so you can use carbon to get difference between current date/time and your model updated_at

```
@if(Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInHours($time->updated_at) > 8)
//time difference is greater than 8
@else
// time difference is less than or equal to 8 hours
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks but seem like doesn't work properly. I've got the form. Whit answer of @scot I didn't get the form.

Comment: as mentioned in answer this would work if you are using laravel timestamps other wise you have to convert updated_at string to carbon instance using
Carbon\Carbon::parse($time->updated_at)
this will work if you are not using laravel eloquent timestamps

Comment: I'm kind of new and still didn't happen to work with `Carbon`. Thank's for the answer.